# interactive doughnut (or pie) chart control for XAML

Tags: xaml, charts, windows-runtime, controls

I need a doughnut control with a similar interactive behavior like this one:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn163530.aspx
(Chart can be rotated by the user so that different Details can be displayed).

Unfortunately this sample control is for HTML/JS only but my app is in XAML.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the [Chart-Controls](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinRT/gallery.xml#!page=chart) from DevExpress. The bad point is, that they are not very cheap.

Comment: Not as cool, as the one from my link, because you can't rotate the chart. But at least it is interactive! Thank you!

Comment: By the way: I ended up using a chart control from ComponentOne.